# empty() returning TRUE on object's non-empty property

Tags: php, object

I've got a very weird and unexpected problem.

`empty()` is returning `TRUE` on a non-empty property for a reason unknown to me.

```
class MyObject
{
    private $_property;

    public function __construct($property)
    {
        $this->_property = $property;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $priv_name = "_{$name}";

        if (isset($this->$priv_name))
        {
            return $this->$priv_name;
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}

$obj = new MyObject('string value');

echo $obj->property;        // Output 'string value'
echo empty($obj->property); // Output 1 (means, that property is empty)
```

Would this mean, that the `__get()` magic function is not called when using `empty()`?

btw. I'm running PHP version 5.0.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that's what it means. `empty` is not your everyday function, it's a language construct that doesn't play by normal rules. Because in fact, `$obj->property` does not exist, so the result is correct.

You'll need to [implement `__isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) for `empty` and `isset` to work.

Comment: This saved me big time, I thought I was going mad when empty() kept returning true for a clearly non-empty array. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `empty` or `isset` with properties, you need to declare a member function called [`__isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).

Here's a possible implementation:

```
public function __isset($name)
{
    $priv_name = "_{$name}";

    return isset($this->$priv_name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset(($this->$priv_name)))
```

Putting **()** around the **Object->Property** value will force it to be evaluated prior to calling `isset`.