# empty() in php returns true for content

Tags: php, class, overriding

I have a class that overrides `__get` before returning a value. How come it always returns true for `empty()`? It acts like if `__call` returns a value after the function empty rather than before.

```
<?php
  class ref_dummy {
    private $_data = array();
    public function __get($name) {
      if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_data)) return $this->_data[$name];
      $this->_data[$name] = 'bar'; // load sample data
      return $this->_data[$name];
    }  
  }

  $dummy = new ref_dummy();

  if (empty($dummy->foo)) echo 'is empty' . '<br/>';
  else echo $dummy->foo . '<br/>';
?>
```

I know if`($dummy->foo)` works but I'm wondering why `empty()` doesn't.

Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dak-fjx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass an empty check you need to implement the magic `__isset`.
in your case it would be as simple as

```
public function __isset($name){
    return isset($this->_data[$name]);
}
```

Comment: @tim you got there the same time i did.

Answer (score 1):

This thread solved my problem: [empty() returning TRUE on object's non-empty property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060420/empty-returning-true-on-objects-non-empty-property?rq=1)

The solution is to use both __get and __isset.

```
  class ref_dummy {

    private $_data = array();

    public function __isset($name) {
      return $this->__get($name);
    }

    public function __get($name) {
      if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_data)) return $this->_data[$name];
      $this->_data[$name] = 'bar'; // load sample data
      return $this->_data[$name];
    }
  }
```